# Submit Form in foreach Loop and call ajax function mvc 4 with it's data only

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

In my view :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // some code
    <form method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="if (!onformsubmitContactUs()) { return false; }">
        <input type="text" value="4" name="id" style="display: none;" />
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="الاسم" required>
        <textarea name="Msg" id="Msg" placeholder="تعليق" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="b" value="ارسال">
    </form>
}
```

Ajax function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onformsubmitContactUs() {
    if ($('#Name').val() != '' && $('#Msg').val() != '') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ($('#Name').val() == '') { $('#Name').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Name').css("borderColor", ""); }
        if ($('#Msg').val() == '') { $('#Msg').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Msg').css("borderColor", ""); }
        return false;
    }


};

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!onformsubmitContactUs()) return false;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddComment", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {

            $('#b').val('sending .......'); // change submit button text
            $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
            $('#Msg').css("borderColor", "");
        },
        success: function (response,textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // There is no problem with the validation
            if (response) {
                $('#b').val('success');
                document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
                $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
                $('#Msg').css("borderColor", "");
            }
            // Problem happend during the validation, display message related to the field.
            $.each(data.Errors, function (key, value) {
                if (value != null) {
                    //$("#Err_" + key).html(value[value.length - 1].ErrorMessage);
                    $("#" + key).css("borderColor", "rgba(247, 5, 5, 0.53)");
                    $('#b').html('send');
                    $('#result').text("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
   });
});


</script>
```

Action controller :

```
    public bool AddComment()
    {
        bool result = false;
        EventComment cuM = new EventComment();
        string Name = Request.Form["Name"], Email = Request.Form["Email"],
                     Message = Request.Form["Msg"];

        cuM.EventId = int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]);
        cuM.Name = Name;
        cuM.Comment = Message;
        cuM.IsSeen = false;
        cuM.IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        cuM.DateAdd = DateTime.Now;
        cuM.Approval = false;
        db.EventComments.Add(cuM);

        db.SaveChanges();
        result = true;

        return result;
    }
```

When submit my form has all data in foreach loop, if content has 3 form after loop , Form.Request has all data like that :

> {id=1,id=2,id=3,Name="00",Name="",Name="",Msg="",...}

Whate make error.

How make each form call ajax with its data only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same element and you've all the forms with same id's so please replace those `id`'s with general classes like :

```
<form method="post" class="myForm" ...>
    <input type="text" value="4" name="id" style="display: none;" />
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="Name" placeholder="الاسم" required>
    <textarea name="Msg" class="Msg" placeholder="تعليق" required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="b" value="ارسال">
</form>
```

Then in your js replace every use of `#b/#myForm/#Name/#Msg` by classes, e.g:

```
$('.myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!onformsubmitContactUs()) return false;

    var _this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddComment", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        data: _this.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.b',_this).val('sending .......'); // change submit button text
            $('.Name',_this).css("borderColor", "");
            $('.Msg',_this).css("borderColor", "");
        },
        ....
}
```

Hope this helps.